# how to find duplicates from a column of a table using arraylist or hashmap

Tags: java, database, arraylist, jdbc, hashmap

I have H2 database. I want to retrieve values of a column into an ArrayList. Then I want to find the duplicate values in a column
and after finding the duplicate columns, I want to set the result column values as duplicate or unique.

I have retrieved the table from SQL Server in JDBC resultset

```
while(resultset.next()){

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add(resultset.getString(1));

Set<String> s =new HashSet<String>();
for(String name: list){
  if(s.add(name)==false){
    System.out.println(name + "is duplicate")
    St.setString(2 ,"Duplicate")
   }
}
```

Here 1 is the column which has IDs, and column 2 has to be set to "Unique" or "duplicate", depending on if count(id)>1.

The problem with ArrayList is it's storing value in list after every time while loop runs, and that's why it is giving "duplicate" output for every id. Can anyone please guide me what I am doing wrong?

Or do I have to use something else in place of ArrayList? For example, is Hashmap be a better option?

Comment: Probably easier to do something like ```select foo from bar group by foo having count(foo) > 1```

Comment: I am using H2DB database in that this query is returning only a blank EarthriseAccount column....can you please suggest how to write this query which will give output for H2DB

Comment: I don't know it. Won't it do sql?

Comment: No my tables are in h2db...thanks for replying

Comment: [Welcome to H2, the Java **SQL** database](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) (My emphasis)